# Custom constraints - postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

This is more of a conceptual doubt. Is there any way in which we can apply a constraint that value of a field can't be blank? I know `NOT NULL` can be used. But I want to check if the field has only spaces, it rejects that value also. For example `"    "` should be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Model's class, you can add a validation like this:

```
validates :field_name, presence: true
```

From the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

> This helper validates that the specified attributes are not empty. It
>   uses the blank? method to check if the value is either nil or a blank
>   string, that is, a string that is either empty or consists of
>   whitespace.

That will ensure that the value of that field can't be blank.

#### When validations are run?

> Creating and saving a new record will send an SQL INSERT operation to
>   the database. Updating an existing record will send an SQL UPDATE
>   operation instead. Validations are typically run before these commands
>   are sent to the database. If any validations fail, the object will be
>   marked as invalid and Active Record will not perform the INSERT or
>   UPDATE operation. This avoids storing an invalid object in the
>   database.

See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: If we do that, would the check be at code level or when data goes to database postgres will check?

Comment: Validations are typically run before the `SQL` commands are sent to the database.

Comment: @SagarGrover look at my updated answer. I explained this a bit there.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the next psql constraints to prevent inserting null or "  " strings in your DB without changing an application logics.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    string character varying(16) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT good_string CHECK (rtrim(string, ' ') != '')
);
```